# Incorrect syntax near '+' using cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, cursor

I can not understand where is my mistake.

I am trying to loop through the table and deliver PDF file that stored in `image` datatype to a particular location.

I wrote the cursor, but it gives me a syntax error next to '+'

```
CREATE TABLE #tblPolicyForms
(
    FormID INT NOT NULL,
    PDF VARBINARY(MAX) NULL,
    PDF_FIlename VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #tblPolicyForms
    SELECT  
        FormID, PDF, PDF_FileName
    FROM    
        [dbo].[tblPolicyForms]
    WHERE   
        FormID IN (19, 20, 21, 22)

--select * from #tblPolicyForms

DECLARE @FormID varchar(4);
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(200);

DECLARE FormID_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT
        FormID, PDF_FIlename
    FROM
        #tblPolicyForms
    WHERE 
        FormID IN (19, 20, 21, 22)
    --where whatever conditions you need to get the FormIDs you want to use

OPEN FormID_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM FormID_cursor INTO @FormID, @FileName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM [MEJAMES].[dbo].tblPolicyForms " queryout "C:\Users\oserdyuk\Documents\ExportDir\'+@FileName+'" -T -N'

    FETCH NEXT FROM FormID_cursor INTO @FormID, @FileName
END

CLOSE FormID_cursor
DEALLOCATE FormID_cursor
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM [MEJAMES].[dbo].tblPolicyForms " queryout "C:\Users\oserdyuk\Documents\ExportDir\'+@FileName+'" -T -N';

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

As from doc [EXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql):

> { value
>                              | @variable [ OUTPUT ]
>                              | [ DEFAULT ]
>                              }

So you could only pass value (literal), variable or default. In your example with `+` you are trying to pass expression which causes error.

---

Note: It is a good practice to end each statement with semicolon.

Comment: Thanks. It brings files now. But for some reason the size of them is 0 KB. So they are empty. In a table PDF column stored as image datatype. Do you think it something to do with that?

Comment: @Oleg You should ask new question. Please note that `image` datatype is obsolete.

Comment: @Oleg Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803870/sql-server-blob-image-column-extracting-with-bcp-queryout-corrupted-files-an maybe it helps you